# How to match two databases, one has no duplicate key values, one has many duplicate key values?

Tags: database, csv, shopify, matching, volusion

Okay, this is going to be a mouthful, but I'm interested to ask this question because I've been learning programming on my own time and I'm wondering if there is a programmatic approach to this problem.

I work at an ecommerce agency, and I have a client who would like to migrate from Volusion to Shopify. Their main concern is migrating their 'product reviews' database from Volusion into Shopify.

There are three .csv files I'm looking at.

- One from Shopify, with SHOPIFY PRODUCT ID's matched to **Product Names**.
- One from Volusion, with *Volusion Product ID's* matched to **Product Names**.
- One from Volusion's Native Reviews, with Product Reviews matched to
  *Volusion Product ID's*.

Problem #1: The product ID's from Volusion do not match the Product ID's from Shopify.

Problem #2: There are multiple product reviews for each Volusion Product ID.

The goal is to match Volusion Product Reviews to SHOPIFY PRODUCT ID's, which would have to be done by:

1. Matching Volusion Product Reviews to *Volusion Product ID's* (Done)
2. Matching *Volusion Product ID's* to SHOPIFY PRODUCT ID's, which are different, but can be done through finding matching **Product Names**

Example of the CSV's:

Shopify Product Export CSV:

```
Product ID    Name
----          ----
2344          Leather Handbag
2345          Phone Case
```

Volusion Product Export CSV:

```
Product ID    Name
----          ----
36754         Leather Handbag
36755         Phone Case
```

Volusion Reviews Export CSV:

```
Product ID    Review
----          ----
36754         Great Bag!
36754         Quality Leather!
36754         Amazing!
36755         Great Phone Case!
```

What would be the quickest way to build a CSV file with three columns: SHOPIFY PRODUCT ID, SHOPIFY PRODUCT NAME, VOLUSION PRODUCT REVIEW, MATCHED TO SHOPIFY PRODUCT ID BY PRODUCT NAME

So that the end result looks like:

```
Product ID    Name               Product Review
----          ----               ----
2344          Leather Handbag    Great Bag!
                                 Quality Leather!
                                 Amazing!
2345          Phone Case         Great Phone Case!
```

Is this possible?

Thanks everybody! :)

Comment: Are product names unique and identical between csv files?

Comment: Great question, the guy who ran the original import says yes, however I just have a bad feeling there could be ONE product name that is different that makes this not true. There are about 600 products in total. Is there a solution for either scenario?